# Time series forecasting via Statsmodels

Tags: python, prediction, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

I used the following code the make some predictions :

Just to give your a quick look at the dataset (df.head()):

```
  places_occupees                date
0              238 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1              238 2017-01-01 00:01:00
2              238 2017-01-01 00:02:00
3              238 2017-01-01 00:03:00
4              238 2017-01-01 00:04:00
```

Then I make predictions for the 7 days to come:

```
X = places.values
train, test = X[1:len(X)-7], X[len(X)-7:]
# On entraîne le modèle d'autoregression
model = AR(train)
model_fit = model.fit()
print('Lag: %s' % model_fit.k_ar)
print('Coefficients: %s' % model_fit.params)
#On effectue des predictions
predictions = model_fit.predict(start=len(train), end=len(train)+len(test)-1, dynamic=False)
```

I get the following output:

[image]

This is how the plot looks like:

[image]

But what I really want to do is to make some predictions for the next 24 hours and not for the next 7 days. How can I do that? How shoud I modify the code above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You should code

```
train, test = X[:-30], X[-30:]
```

Comment: Hi xoyox, welcome to SO. It's unclear from your post what this modification would achieve and how would that solve OP's problem? Please edit your answer to provide explanation as to how this answers the question.